# Get key value for selected option in select using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, select, key-value

I have a JSON like

```
quarterJson = [{"quarter_id":1, "quarter":"Quarter 1", "end_date":'31.03.'},
               {"quarter_id":2, "quarter":"Quarter 2", "end_date":'30.06.'},
               {"quarter_id":3, "quarter":"Quarter 3", "end_date":'31.09.'},
               {"quarter_id":4, "quarter":"Quarter 4", "end_date":'31.12.'}];
```

and using it populate options of a select box

```
$('#quarterSel').empty();
$('#quarterSel').append('<option value="0">--Select--</option>');
$.each(quarterJson ,function(idx,ob){
$('#quarterSel').append
('<option value="'+ob[quarter_id]+'">'+ob[quarter]+'</option>');
```

Now I want to get value of `"end_date"` for selected option in select box `quarterSel`. I could get this using below code

```
var quarter_end_date = '';
$.each(quarterJson, function()
{
    if(this.quarter_id == $('#quarterSel').val())
    {
        quarter_end_date = this.end_date;
        return false;
    }
});
```

Is there a better way (avoiding loops) for doing this?
Thanks..

Comment: if your select box value and index of value in array is same then use this code

alert(quarterJson[($('#quarterSel').val()-1)].end_date);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can use **Grep** Function to Get The value

```
      var arrayfeedback ;
     arrayfeedback = jQuery.grep(quarterJson, function (n, i) {
                            return parseInt(quarter_id) == +$('#quarterSel').val()
                        });
      quarter_end_date=arrayfeedback[0].end_date ;
```

Comment: No it Doesn't Require any loop... !!

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data associated with an option using the data api and then use it to get the end date

```
$('#quarterSel').empty();
$('#quarterSel').append('<option value="0">--Select--</option>');
$.each(quarterJson, function (idx, ob) {
    $('<option/>', {
        text: ob.quarter,
        value: ob.quarter_id
    }).data('data', ob).appendTo('#quarterSel');

});

var data = $('#quarterSel option:selected').data('data');
var quarter_end_date = data ? data.end_date : '';
```

Comment: The code for populating select box using json is done in a another file which I can't modify